# Ciphering through the non letters

Tags: python, python-3.x

So here's my problem...I’m trying to make it so any character not part of the alphabet isn’t shifted in the text file but it does 'take up' a shift amount. For example, if I wanted to implement 2 shift amounts - 3 shifts and 4 shifts - to the statement "alarm clock" the a would be shifted by 3, the l by 4, the second a by 3, r by 4, m by 3, and then the space wouldnt be shifted but would "take up" a space, so it would cause the c to shift by 3. Here's what I have so far

```
import sys

file = input("Enter input file: ")
shifts = input("Enter shift amounts: ").split()
code = input("Encode (E) or Decode (D)?")
if code == "E":
    with open(file) as f:
        lines = f.read().replace("e","zw").splitlines()
     for line in lines:
        mid = len(line) // 2
        line_list = list(line)
        line_list.insert(mid,'hokie')
        new_line = ('hokie' + (''.join(line_list) + 'hokie'))
        for index, char in enumerate(new_line):
            index = index % len(shifts)

            print(chr(ord(char)+int(shifts[index])),end='')

        print()
```

example input:

file text:

Though Birnam Wood be come to Dunsinane,
And thou opposed, being of no woman born,
Yet I will try the last. Before my body
I throw my warlike shield. Lay on, Macduff;
And damned be him that first cries "Hold, enough!"
-- MacBeth

shift:

3 4 5 6 7

result:

kspolWltank Goyqer Drsi icltqpha ivpdb ar Iauvmsguca,nvnmj
kspolDri aksz vsttygzh, icltqphantn sk ur butdr hvur,nvnmj
kspolBdbz L boso yxf xmfd pmurlifya. Hgzjtxgz re esieoronk
kspolL ynyra sf afxsloec vlnnvnmjfdoh. Oed vq, Shfhzlm;ltqph
kspolDri kdqsfdg gfd lns wlfz immurliwya gwogzw "Orpi, casubjl!"oronk
kspol-- ShkspolfFecakltqph

Comment: Could you add some example input and expected output?

Comment: Yep just did you can see how the spaces and other punctuation marks are not affected

Answer (score 1):

you have to add a `if`,here my solution.for the punctuation，
please look[Best way to strip punctuation from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string-in-python)

```
import string
exclude = set(string.punctuation)
shifts = [3,4]
lines = ["alarm clock", "alarm   ';.clock"]
for line in lines:
    mid = len(line) // 2
    line_list = list(line)
    line_list.insert(mid,'hokie')
    new_line = ('hit' + (''.join(line_list) + 'hit'))
    index = 0
    for char in new_line:
        index = index % len(shifts)
        if(char in exclude):
            print(char,end='')
            continue
        print(chr(ord(char)+int(shifts[index])),end='')
        index += 1
```

Comment: That's what I thought just wanted to make sure. Why would the inputs need to be lists though?

Comment: i just  follow you code,why you have to add some string in the mid of each line?`new_line = ('hit' + (''.join(line_list) + 'hit'))`is also bad.

Comment: Cuz I have to insert a string in the middle of it and then after that encrypt it. I have the insertion down and also the encryption, but I'm having a tough time trying to work around the additional characters and spaces

Comment: you may need `re`module.

Comment: I don;t really want to strip I just want to make it so it's not encrypted but still takes up a shift space

Comment: read the code,if find punctuation,match ,we skip by print it.it's same find punctuation,strip it.both use same technology.@Chris